# Documents required for Remote developer to show

Tags: legal, remote

I am working for a client for 8 years. I have been hired as a freelancer via the Freelancing platform and after that, I have handled the product single-handed. I am now seeking an opportunity to migrate to a different country and I have to show the employment-related documents to Embassy. I have not collected many documents from clients because I wasn't aware of this situation.

For now, I have collected an employment reference letter from a client as what my immigration consultant has suggested but I want to know the full list of documents that a remote developer should have who are working on a contract or freelance basis for a long time.

Comment: I think you'd need to contact the Embassy for this.

Comment: Thank you @Scott, I have got information about the Employment Reference letter from the Immigration consultant. But I want to know if there any other documents which are important and I am missing?

Comment: Like any business, one should really keep records of everything.. communications, transactions, accounting, taxes, etc.

Answer (score 1):

*Any* business, freelance or otherwise, would be wise to retain **everything** related to that business for at least seven years, if not longer.

You should have files for communications, taxes, accounting, transaction records, contracts, etc.

For **physical records** (receipts, print outs, letters, etc), I have files where I store and sort such records. Well, not really "files". I simply throw these things in a box I have in my office. Then in January of every year I close the box. Write the preceding year on the exterior, and store the box out of the way. Then start a new box for the new year.

For **digital records**, I create a directory titled for the year, then zip the directory and back it up in at least 3 locations, one off-site. Although I do this in January for the preceding year, I do tend to keep these digital items available for at least another year. Most of the records are in the form of emails, so I do an archive of my email accounts and back those up. Knowing they've already been backed up, I delete items when it's clear I no longer need to be able to access anything with regularly - i.e. if a client is gone, I can delete their emails knowing I have them backed up. I can always unarchive the emails and gain access again should I need. When I started out would print emails, but that quickly became untenable due to the lack of any "search" function and the sheer amount of paper/toner it took. Keeping things digital makes it much easier to find something later.

I'm *not* saying this is the absolute proper way to do anything, merely how I've handled it.